# Should outside libraries be wrapped?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I have been using two libraries, SFML and Box2D, while at the same time taking great pain to ensure none of their functions or classes are exposed in the main body of my code, hiding them behind classes that serve little more than to act as a mediator between my code and the library itself.  My mediators take the following form:

```
    class MyWindow{
    public:
        // could be 10 or so functions like below
        int doSomething(int arg){
           return library_window->doSomething(arg);
        };
    private:
        library::window * library_window;
    };
```

The benefit to this, at least what I've been told, is that my main code body is not reliant upon the library, in such a way that if it changes or I choose to use a different one, say SDL or OpenGL in place of SFML or something, I can switch by merely amending the mediator classes.  But the  pain of having to code an access point into every feature I want to use is painful and repetitive...

Is this really how professional programmers are supposed to treat external libraries?  And is it worth it?

Am I even doing this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the wrapper technique you're describing is that your wrapper is transparent (in the true sense of that word) -- every method in the library is still visible to you through the wrapper, with the same semantics, same preconditions, etc. You can "see right through" your wrapper.

A transparent wrapper like that is useful to you only if you someday switch the underlying library to something that has identical semantics, or at least very nearly identical semantics. Consider this example. Let's say the library was the std::fstream, and your application needed to read and write files, and lets say that you diligently wrote a wrapper:

```
class MyFile {
    std::fstream* fst;
public:
    void writeData(void* data, size_t count) {
        fst->write((const char*) data, count);
    }
    void readData(void* buffer, size_t count) {
        fst->read((char*) data, count);
    }
    // etc, etc.
};
```

Now let's say you want (or need) to switch to asynchronous I/O with non-blocking reads and writes. There's simply no way that your transparent wrapper is going to help you make that transition. The asynchronous read requires two methods, one to start the read operation and one to confirm that the read has completed. It also requires a commitment from the application that the buffer won't be used in between those two method calls.

When all is said and done, a library interface wrapper is useful only when very carefully designed to not be transparent (good interfaces are opaque). Furthermore, to be useful, the library you are wrapping must be something that you are intimately familiar with. So, boost::filesystem can "wrap" the pathnames for both DOS and Unix because the authors know intimately POSIX, UNIX and DOS pathnames and are designing the "wrapper" to effectively encapsulate those implementations.

From what you've described, it seems to me that your effort is going to end up wasted. Simple is better than complicated, and unless the wrapper is really encapsulating something (i.e., hiding the underlying library), direct is better than indirect.

That's not a license to write spaghetti -- your application still needs structure and isolation of the major components (e.g., isolate the UI from the actual calculations/simulations/document that your application provides). If you do that right, swapping the library some day will be a manageable task without any wrapper code.

Comment: The transparency vs. opaque analogy is a good way of visualizing it, thanks!  Marking this the answer since it also touches points from other answers and brings them together as a whole, too.  I'll be rewriting my wrapper from the ground up then, this time adding functionality and simplicity instead of just laying on top of the library lazily.

Answer (score 4):

Not worth it.  Just use the libraries.  If you end up wanting to change to a different third-party library, you'll end up needing to change your application code anyway...otherwise what was the point of changing in the first place, if everything works the same in both versions anyway.

Friends don't let friends over-engineer.  Just say no.

Comment: I can't argue with that, haha

Comment: In this case it doesn't really hurt to do so since it just makes it easier to call a method that does the work you need rather than just coding the library directly into the app, if you know you're going to add more this is just going to be a mess later on.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap something under two circumstances:

1. You have reason to believe you might change it. And I don't mean "well, one day, maybe kinda." I mean you have some real belief that you might switch libraries. Alternatively, if you need to support more than one library. Maybe you allow a choice between using SDL and SFML. Or whatever.
2. You are providing an abstraction of that functionality. That is, you're not just making a thin wrapper; you're *improving* on that functionality. Simplifying the interface, adding features, etc.

Comment: Going by those two stipulations, I don't have number 1, and I failed at number 2.  Makes the choice pretty clear for me

Comment: This was a hard call, almost made yours the answer for it's brevity.  If I could upvote it twice I would though.  I like that my problem with SO is there are too many good answers.

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

If you are using a very mature library and you probably won't migrate to other implementations, the mediator class is not necessary. For example, have you ever encapsulated stl or boost library?

On the other hand, if the library you are using is new or there are many alternatives around, then an abstraction might be useful.

Comment: I'm of the opinion they're both very mature, so it'd fall into the first.  ... well, maybe not as mature as STL, but mature enough!

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct you should code basic functionality that your program needs and write a wrapper that wraps (redundant...) the libraries to do what you need. Simply when adding a new library you just write a new wrapper and you can simply just swap out the underlying wrappers from underneath your program without it having to care. If you separate your worries then its much easier to add functionality later because you don't have to find where you're using functions or use complicated #ifdef statements to switch out libraries you would just use some simple #ifdef to define something like

```
#ifdef LIB_A
typedef MyGfxClassA MyGfxClass;
#endif
```

etc...

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and it's applicable to a decently built wrapper.  But I'm seeing my implementation of a 'wrapper' was flawed at a more fundamental level, as someone else pointed out, it's a '1 to 1 translation'.

Comment: A wrapper should be a translation of required functionality. If you need to draw a square you have a drawSquare method that does so and you build your application logic with that in mind, only the library needs to care not the application.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea if you want to provide a simpler interface([Convention over Configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)).  But if you are simply going to provide a 1-to-1 translation of all the utilities in the library, then it's not really worth it.

Comment: The 1-to-1 ratio was me misunderstanding the purpose of a wrapper.  I actually have classes that simplify the library into making my most common use of them the 'default' and easiest to use.  I'm going to just add to that, considering those helping classes and functions my 'wrapper', and get rid of the needless delegation between them and the library.  Thanks